# How to delete duplicate phrases in a text file?

Tags: java, c++, regex, duplicates

Okay so I have about 1000 duplicated phrases in this file, so doing this manually is not an option.
Note that these are PHRASES, not lines or words, and each "phrase" is about 10 lines long.

I am trying to get rid of duplicate phrases, yet the only thing that renders an "item" (or phrase) a duplicate is the position syntax. For Example:

```
    class Item0
    {
        position[]={4347.6001,0,3214.6399};
        azimut=128.81599;
        special="NONE";
        id=1;
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Land_fortified_nest_small";
        lock="UNLOCKED";
        skill=0.2;
        init="this setPos [4347.6, 3214.64, 0]; this setDir 128.816;";
    };
    class Item1
    {
        position[]={4347.6001,0,3214.6399};
        azimut=128.81599;
        special="NONE";
        id=2;
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Land_fortified_nest_small";
        lock="UNLOCKED";
        skill=0.2;
        init="this setPos [4347.6, 3214.64, 0]; this setDir 128.816;";
    };
```

Now the previous two phrases are duplicates, yet the ID and ITEM# are different, so the only way to identify duplicate phrases is through the position[]={} parameter. When 2 phrases have the same position, these two phrases ARE duplicates, regardless or the ID or ITEM#.

So my goal is to use some type of code, script, program, or regular expression to delete all duplicate phrases, but leaving the first duplicate untouched. So if there are three duplicates, one phrase is left but the two are deleted. How would I go about doing this?

---

*An example of the desired input/output:*

### **Input:**

```
    class Item0
    {
        position[]={4347.6001,0,3214.6399};
        azimut=128.81599;
        special="NONE";
        id=1;
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Land_fortified_nest_small";
        lock="UNLOCKED";
        skill=0.2;
        init="this setPos [4347.6, 3214.64, 0]; this setDir 128.816;";
    };
        class Item1
    {
        position[]={4682.6001,0,3847.6399};
        azimut=128.81599;
        special="NONE";
        id=2;
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Land_fortified_nest_small";
        lock="UNLOCKED";
        skill=0.2;
        init="this setPos [4682.6, 3847.64, 0]; this setDir 128.816;";
    };
        class Item2
    {
        position[]={4347.6001,0,3214.6399};
        azimut=128.81599;
        special="NONE";
        id=3;
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Land_fortified_nest_small";
        lock="UNLOCKED";
        skill=0.2;
        init="this setPos [4347.6, 3214.64, 0]; this setDir 128.816;";
    };
```

### **Output:**

```
    class Item0
    {
        position[]={4347.6001,0,3214.6399};
        azimut=128.81599;
        special="NONE";
        id=1;
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Land_fortified_nest_small";
        lock="UNLOCKED";
        skill=0.2;
        init="this setPos [4347.6, 3214.64, 0]; this setDir 128.816;";
    };
        class Item1
    {
        position[]={4682.6001,0,3847.6399};
        azimut=128.81599;
        special="NONE";
        id=2;
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Land_fortified_nest_small";
        lock="UNLOCKED";
        skill=0.2;
        init="this setPos [4682.6, 3847.64, 0]; this setDir 128.816;";
    };
```

Comment: create your own `equals` method that compares the Items how you want to and then get rid of any ones that match any of the other ones.

Comment: Ad "regex" tag: this can't be done with regular expressions, because the language of this problem (to find duplicates) is not regular.

Answer (score 0):

My initial approach would be:

1. create an array to store the unique positions
2. parse the file, if the position is in the array, skip. Else, output to file & store in array.
3. Loop until EOF

This will give you what you want but is not the optimal solution. Consider ways to store the first encounter of an item, and how you will check for it later (scanning an array can take while).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a class type then you can consider using a SET and add the class elements.

```
      Set<Item> itemSet  = new HashSet<Item>;
      itemSet.add(new Item());
```

by the end of adding all the items you will remain with only the unique items.

You can keep the id out of the contention and still keep a check on what ids are inserted by checking if the item was inserted. This will work considering that the IDs are in order. To keep the id out use a new class that has the same data members excluding the id.

I have used a different example(It was easy to build) hope it helps

```
    int item[] = null;
    int offset = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> duplicateids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> afterDups= new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i : item) {
        counter++;
        //you can create a new class excluding the id and initialize it here
        if(!afterDups.add(i))
            duplicateids.add(counter);
    }
```

EDIT :

Okay I missed the thing of picking from the file, so adding this answer. You can check each line, and given that your file is of this form you will not like to compare `Class Item0` and `id=1;` lines. Rest you can read the file line by line and place it in a string. Once a class is complete(indicated by the starting of the line as `class`) you can set into creating another string for the text. You will seperate the data from the credentials(`id` and `class`). Use a separator from which you can split the string again and recreate the file.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        String seperator = "$$";
        //this contains the $$ seperated class data items
        String currentClassText = "";
        //this contains the $$ seperated class name the opening braces and the closing braces
        String  currentClassCredentilas= "";
        Set<String> texts = new HashSet<String>();
        ArrayList<String> credentials = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            if(strLine.contains("id=") || strLine.contains("class") || strLine.contains("};"))
                currentClassCredentilas.concat(strLine + seperator);
            else
                currentClassText.concat(strLine + seperator);

            //check if the class has completed
            if(strLine.contains("};")){
                //text is not a duplicate
                if(texts.add(currentClassText)){
                    credentials.add(currentClassCredentilas + seperator);
                }
                //set everything back to empty for the next round
                currentClassCredentilas = currentClassText = "";
            }
            System.out.println (strLine);
        }
        in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would generate Hash value of each phrase and store it into a map. Keep adding new phrases and ignore if one already exist. Hash code and map values are is unique always so you wont have duplicates.